# Separate characters and numbers from a string

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string variable that contain character and numbers like this

```
var sampleString = "aaa1211"
```

Note that variable always start with a `character/s` and end with `number/s`. Character and number size is not fixed. It could be something like followings

```
var sampleString = "aaaaa12111"
var sampleString = "aaa12111"
```

I need to separate the characters and numbers and assign them into separate variables.

How could I do that ?

I try to use split and substring but for this scenario I couldn't apply those. I know this is a basic question but i'm search over the internet and I was unable to find an answer.

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please use
[A-Za-z] - all letters (uppercase and lowercase)
[0-9] - all numbers

```
        function myFunction() {
        var str = "aaaaAZE12121212";
        var patt1 = /[0-9]/g;
        var patt2 = /[a-zA-Z]/g;
        var letters = str.match(patt2);
        var digits = str.match(patt1);
        document.getElementById("alphabets").innerHTML = letters;
     document.getElementById("numbers").innerHTML = digits;
    }
```

Codepen-http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/pbbGOB

Comment: This returns array

Comment: @J4GD33P51NGH, yes , as SO mentioned that letters and numbers should be assigned to separate variables

Answer (score 5):

You can use it in a single regex,

```
var st = 'red123';
var regex = new RegExp('([0-9]+)|([a-zA-Z]+)','g');
var splittedArray = st.match(regex);

var num= splittedArray[0];
var text = splittedArray[1];
```

this will give you both the text and number.

Answer (score 5):

A shorter solution if the string always starts with letters and ends with numbers as you say:

```
var str = 'aaaaa12111';

var chars = str.slice(0, str.search(/\d/));
var numbs = str.replace(chars, '');

console.log(chars, numbs);
```

Answer (score 4):

### Using **Match**

```js
const str = "ASDF1234";
const [word, digits] = str.match(/\D+|\d+/g);

console.log(word);    // "ASDF"
console.log(digits);  // "1234"
```

The above will work even if your string starts with digits.

### Using **Split**

with Positive lookbehind `(?<=)` and Positive lookahead `(?=)`:

```js
const str = "ASDF1234";
const [word, digits] = str.split(/(?<=\D)(?=\d)/);

console.log(word);    // "ASDF"
console.log(digits);  // "1234"
```

where `\D` stands for ***not a digit*** and `\d` for ***digit***.

Answer (score 0):

Use isNaN() to differentiate

```
var sampleString = "aaa1211"  
var newnum =""
var newstr =""
for(var i=0;i<sampleString.length;i++){
 if(isNaN(sampleString[i])){

 newstr = newstr+sampleString[i]

   }else{

  newnum= newstr+sampleString[i]
  }

  }


  console.log(newnum) //1121
  console.log(newstr) //aaa
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're like me, you were looking to separate alphabets and numbers, no matter what their position is, Try this:

```
var separateTextAndNum = (x) => {
    var textArray = x.split('')
    var text = []
    var num = []
    textArray.forEach(t=>{
        if (t>-1) {
            num.push(t)
        } else {
            text.push(t)
        }
    })
    return [text, num]
}
```

For ex - if you try this:

```
separateTextAndNum('abcd1234ava') // result [["a","b","c","d","a","v","a"],["1","2","3","4"]]
```

Answer (score -1):

This isn't beautiful but it works.

```
function splitLettersAndNumbers(string) {
  var numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
  var numbers, letters, splitIndex;

  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    if (numbers.indexOf(string[i]) > -1) {
      letters = string.substring(0, i);
      numbers = string.substring(i);
      return [letters, numbers];
    }
  }

  // in the chance that you don't find any numbers just return the initial string or array of the string of letters
  return [string];
}
```

Essentially just looping through the string until you find a number and you split it at that index. Returning a tuple with your letters and numbers. So when you run it you can do something like this:

```
var results = splitLettersAndNumbers(string);
var letters = results[0];
var numbers = results[1];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can loop through the string length, check  it & add to the variable.

It is not clear if you want to assign each of the character to a variable or all alphabets to one variable & integers to another.

```js
var sampleString = "aaa12111"
var _num = "";
var _alp = "";

for (var i = 0; i < sampleString.length; i++) {
  if (isNaN(sampleString[i])) {
    _num += sampleString[i];
  } else {
    _alp += sampleString[i];
  }
}
console.log(_num, _alp)
```

Answer (score -1):

A functional approach...

```js
var sampleString = "aaaaa12111";

var seperate = sampleString.split('').reduce(function(start , item){
  Number(item) ? start[0] += item : start[1] += item;
  return start
},['',''])

console.log(seperate) //["12111", "aaaaa"]
```

Comment: For `E09` it returns `[ '9', 'E0' ]`